# VTK5.10, QT4: Refresh Renderer on updated points

Tags: c++11, qt4, vtk

I've tried so much, but I don't get this work.

I want to build up an QT4 Application with an QVTK Widget.
Sadly I need to use QT4 and therefore VTK 5.10.

There is an `vtkActor` that is dealing with some `vtkPoints` that should be rendered (nothing fancy, more or less from the Examples from VTK). Here is the pipeline initialization:

```
m_pdata = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();

m_pdata->SetPoints(m_points);

m_vfilter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkVertexGlyphFilter>::New();
m_vfilter->SetInputConnection(m_pdata->GetProducerPort());
m_vfilter->Update();

m_vdata = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();

m_vdata->ShallowCopy(m_vfilter->GetOutput());

m_mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();

m_mapper->SetInputConnection(m_vdata->GetProducerPort());

m_pactor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
m_pactor->SetMapper(m_mapper);
m_pactor->GetProperty()->SetPointSize(2);

m_renderer->AddActor(m_pactor);
```

After this the App calls `m_rwindow->Render()` to render the scene ...

Then I have an QT `QLineEdit` to add a Point to the `vtkPoints`, like this:

```
m_points->InsertNextPoint(point[0], point[1], point[2]);
```

And I want to refresh the view, so that the new point will be rendered too.
But this will not happen ...

I tried to Update the pipeline like this (more or less in every constellation):

```
m_pdata->Modified();
m_pdata->Update();
m_vfilter->Modified();
m_vfilter->Update();
m_vdata->Modified();
m_vdata->Update();
m_mapper->Modified();
m_mapper->Update();
m_pactor->Modified();
```

After this update process I called `m_rwindow->Render()` again.

But everything I get updated will be the old points (for example the color, or size of points ...).

Is it possible to rerender the points so the new Points are displayed too?

Comment: Can you try calling `m_rwindow->Render()` once more at the end of all the `Modified()` and `Update()` calls?

Comment: Oh I have forget to mention, that - of cause - I called `Render()` again, after modifying / updating!